# Recuperar usuário logado

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee

Tenho aplicação Java Web, porém quero faze o seguinte:

Quando eu logar em minha aplicação com um determinado usuário então eu preciso fazer algumas operações, como por exemplo salvar algumas informações no banco, só que eu quero que na hora de eu fazer essa inserção eu capto qual o usuário que fez essa inserção, quero pegar o usuaŕio. Como posso fazer isso?

Código do botão que faço a ação de inserir:

```
<p:commandLink id="btn_save_users_modal"
               action="#{messageBean.insert()}"
               styleClass="btn btn-success"
               update=":message_form"
               validateClient="true">
    <i class="fa fa-check fa-fw" /> #{bundle['system.ui.label.save']}
 </p:commandLink>
```

Método abaixo `messageBean.insert()` faz a inserção:

```
public void insert() {       
    try {    
        messageFacade.save(message);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Aqui, por exemplo, quero fazer a inserção desse meu objeto `message` e juntamente com o usuário que acabei de logar na minha página.

Quero saber qual usuário que fez essa inserção de acordo com cada usuário que logar na minha página.

Esse é o meu metodo de login(), quando logo na pagina faz algumas validaçoes.

```
public String doLogin() {

    // Força a JVM para pt-BR, assim a formatação numérica fica no formato
    // brasileiro
    Locale.setDefault(new Locale("pt", "BR"));

    // Validações

    if (this.username == null || this.username.equals("")) {
        MessageGrowl.warn(
                MessageProperties.getString("message.loginVazio"), false);
    } else if (this.password == null || this.password.equals("")) {
        MessageGrowl
                .warn(MessageProperties.getString("message.passwordVazio"),
                        false);
    } else {

        // String hashedPassword = SecurityUtils.getHashedString(password);

        this.loggedUser = loginUserFacade.getValideUser(username,password);

        if (this.loggedUser != null) {
            isAuthenticated = true;
            redirectIfAlreadyLogged();

        }

        else {

            MessageGrowl.error(MessageProperties
                    .getString("login.autenticacao"));
            clear();
        }
    }

    return "";
}
```

Comment: Ivan, poste o código do seu login no sistema e lembre de ocultar qualquer informação que possa comprometer a segurança da sua aplicação.

Comment: Pelo que intendi você que fazer uma Auditoria no seu sistema ? Caso seja essa a sua duvida segue link. https://michelzanini.wordpress.com/2008/09/22/aop-na-pratica/

Comment: Fiz a edição da minha pergunta, colocando o metodo login()

Answer (score 1):

Quando o usuário efetuar o login, você pode adicioná-lo na sessão HTTP:

```
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
    .getExternalContext().getSession(true);

session.setAttribute("usuario", usuario);
```

E então resgatá-lo quando quiser:

```
Usuario usuarioLogado = (Usuario) session.getAttribute("usuario");
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que seu método `doLogin()` esteja num `ManagedBean` correto?
Basta inserir o seu managedbean que faz o login como uma property dos demais managedbeans para ter o usuário logado.

Ex:

```
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{loginMB}")
private LoginMB loginMB;
public void setLoginMB(LoginMB loginMB) {this.loginMB = loginMB;}

public void insert() {       
    //pegando o usuario: loginMB.getUsername();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para inserir algo no banco no momento que o usuário fizer autenticação, eu faço direto na minha classe de serviço.

```
@Transactional
public Usuario verificaLoginSenha(String email, String senha) {
    Usuario usuario = usuarioDao.verificaLoginSenha(email,senha);
    if(usuario!=null){
        if(usuario.getCadastroAtivo()){
            logAutenticacaoService.salvar(new LogAutenticacao(new Date(),usuario));             
        }
    }
    return usuario;
}
```

Para outras verificações durante a navegação do usuário, recomendo um Bean de sessão